# example GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I have a table with two columns (case and subcase)
and the following values:

```
case subcase
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    4
```

I want to have a list of cases only having subcase(s)
like:

```
case  list_of_subcase
1     2,3
4     6
5     0
```

Cases 2,3,and 6 are not listed because they are subcases.

Case 5 have no subcases but is not subcase itself.

How to write proper select? Any help?

Comment: Note that NULL is commonly used to identify orphans - and CASE is a reserved word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we in danger of overthinking this...

```
DROP TABLE my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(my_case INT NOT NULL
,subcase INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1    ,NULL),
(2    ,1),
(3    ,1),
(4    ,NULL),
(5    ,NULL),
(6    ,4);

SELECT x.my_case
     , GROUP_CONCAT(y.my_case) subcases 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.subcase = x.my_case 
 WHERE x.subcase IS NULL 
 GROUP 
    BY x.my_case;
+---------+----------+
| my_case | subcases |
+---------+----------+
|       1 | 2,3      |
|       4 | 6        |
|       5 | NULL     |
+---------+----------+
```

Comment: Works like a charm. This is exact what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is getting the filtering right -- to keep "5", but not the other subcases.

```
select (case when c.subcase = 0 then c.case else c.subcase) as subcase, 
       group_concat(c.case)
from cases c 
where c.subcase = 0 or
      (c.subcase = 0 and 
       not exists (select 1 from cases c2 where c2.subcase = c.case)
      )
group by (case when c.subcase = 0 then c.case else c.subcase end);
```

EDIT:

It might be easier just to phrase this using `union all`:

```
select c.subcase, group_concat(c.case)
from cases c 
where c.subcase = 0 
group by c.subcase
union all
select c.case, 0
from cases c
group by c.case
having sum(c.subcase <> 0) = 0;
```

Comment: @Strawberry . . . They always do.  Thank you.